# Cleanest way to make itemize ragged right?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize

I want to make my itemize text ragged right. Is there a cleaner way than to redefine the `\@item[#1]{...}` from `latex.ltx`? This is what I have done now:

```
\def\@item[#1]{%
  \if@noparitem
...
  \everypar{%
    \raggedright %    <----
    \@minipagefalse
...
    \fi
    \hskip \labelsep}%
  \ignorespaces}
```

This works fine, but perhaps there is another easy to use hook? I know I can put this in a package and load it, but I ask for the correct way to change this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, but what about

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{ritemize}{\begin{itemize}\raggedright}{\end{itemize}}
\begin{document}

\begin{ritemize}
 \item \lipsum[1-2]
\end{ritemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a quick follow-up comment: I would also load the `ragged2e` package and then use the command `\RaggedRight` (instead of `\raggedright`) inside the new environment. That way, hyphenation is still enabled.